# Write data in Apache Parquet format

Tags: java, hadoop, parquet

I'm having a scheduler that gets our cluster metrics and writes the data onto a HDFS file using an older version of the Cloudera API. But recently, we updated our JARs and the original code errors with an exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.ParquetHiveRecord
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.write.DataWritableWriteSupport.write(DataWritableWriteSupport.java:31)
at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:116)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.write(ParquetWriter.java:324)
```

I need help in using the ParquetHiveRecord class write the data (which are POJOs) in parquet format.

Code sample below:

```
Writable[] values = new Writable[20];
... // populate values with all values
ArrayWritable value = new ArrayWritable(Writable.class, values);
writer.write(value); // <-- Getting exception here
```

Details of "writer" (of type ParquetWriter):

```
MessageType schema = MessageTypeParser.parseMessageType(SCHEMA); // SCHEMA is a string with our schema definition
ParquetWriter<ArrayWritable> writer = new ParquetWriter<ArrayWritable>(fileName, new 
DataWritableWriteSupport() {
    @Override
    public WriteContext init(Configuration conf) {
        if (conf.get(DataWritableWriteSupport.PARQUET_HIVE_SCHEMA) == null)
            conf.set(DataWritableWriteSupport.PARQUET_HIVE_SCHEMA, schema.toString());
    }
});
```

Also, we were using CDH and CM 5.5.1 before, now using 5.8.3

Thanks!

Comment: Without any code we can't help you. Please provide your source code

Comment: Sure, have updated the question with the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `DataWritableWriter` rather than `ParquetWriter`.  The class cast exception indicates the write support class is expecting an instance of `ParquetHiveRecord` instead of `ArrayWritable`.  `DataWritableWriter` likely breaks down the individual records in `ArrayWritable` to individual messages in the form of `ParquetHiveRecord` and sends each to the write support.

Parquet is sort of mind bending at times.  :)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I did try using `DataWritableWriter`, but I did not understand what the `RecordConsumer` class is supposed to be used for! :(

Can you please provide an example if possible? I tried a full day trying to understand it and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of  the DataWritableWriteSupport class:
https ://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/parquet/write/DataWritableWriteSupport.java
You can see it is using the DataWritableWriter, hence you do not need to create an instance of DataWritableWriter, the idea of Write support is that you will be able to write different formats to parquet.

What you do need is to wrap your writables in ParquetHiveRecord